# How to show Python print() in html div

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am using Django to write my website. During writing my Python code I have many print functions. They all are shown in standard console. I would like to show (live without refreshing a page) all my prints in div in my HTML code not only in console. How to do that? 
My code do:
You press button then selenium starts using ajax without refreshing page and during that I would like to show progress on a page using div.

For example, my code:

```
views.py
bot = Instagram()

class InstabotFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LoginInstagramForm
    template_name = 'instabot.html'
    success_url = 'runinstabot.html'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(InstabotFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(InstabotFormView, self).form_valid(form)
        login = form.cleaned_data.get('login')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        tagi = form.cleaned_data.get('tags')
        func = form.cleaned_data.get('function')
        tags = []
        tagi = tagi.split(',')
        tags.extend(tagi)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print('It is AJAX')
            bot.login(login,password)
            bot.search(tags)
            if func == '1':
                bot.downloadPhoto(tags)
            elif func == '2':
                bot.doCalculation(tags)
            print(tags)
            data = {
                'message': "Succesfully  opened Selenium."
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response
```

---

```
Instagram()
    def downloadPhoto(self):
        i = 0
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        print('Start function downloadPhoto')
        print(self.myCurrentList)

        for photo in self.myCurrentList:
            followerPhoto = self.myCurrentList.index(photo) + 1
            print(followerPhoto)
```

How to show all prints from def downloadPhoto(self) in html div?

Comment: You're approaching this incorrectly - the only way to get the contents of your print statements returned from your view is by not printing them, and instead placing them into the contents of your response. The print statement should not be used, based on what you're trying to achieve here. Another way to explain the problem with what you're doing is that you're asking if Django can return *two* responses: one being the content(s) of your print statements, and the other being your JsonResponse object - that's just not how things are intended to work - Django wants to return *one* response.

Comment: thank you for your reply, so what should I do?

Comment: I'll provide an answer below, although I'm not certain it'll be that helpful - but I'll be able to show some possible alterations to your code which *may* be a starting point for you.

Answer (score 3):

The print should be never used in a django app. If you want to print useful information, you must use the logging facility provided by python and well document in django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/

To send notifications in real time to your client, you must implement a `full duplex` channel between the client and the server. The technology that let you do that is the `websocket`, you can use the package django-channels to implement the websocket in your project. Keep in mind that some changes to your infrastructure are necessary.

- Django-channels package: https://github.com/django/channels
- A tutorial: https://realpython.com/getting-started-with-django-channels/

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough attempt at some changes, although I'm not certain it's exactly what you're looking for. Ultimately, you need to get the HTML content that you're scraping with Selenium into your view's `data` dictionary, so that it's part of the content that will be rendered by the `JsonResponse`.

Regarding the `Instagram` class, I'm not clear on why you're printing out `self.myCurrentList`, so I'm skipping that for now.

```
Instagram()
    def downloadPhoto(self):
        i = 0
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        # don't do this: 
        # print('Start function downloadPhoto')
        # not sure if this is needed or not, skipping it for now:
        # print(self.myCurrentList)

        photos = []
        for photo in self.myCurrentList:
            photos.append(self.myCurrentList.index(photo) + 1)

        return photos

# views.py
bot = Instagram()
class InstabotFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            # set a variable to hold the output from Instagram.downloadPhoto
            photos = None 
            # get rid of this:
            # print('It is AJAX')
            bot.login(login,password)
            bot.search(tags)
            if func == '1':
                # capture the output from Instagram.downloadPhoto
                photos = bot.downloadPhoto(tags)
            elif func == '2':
                bot.doCalculation(tags)

            # can't do this, needs to be moved into the data for your JsonResponse:
            # print(tags)
            data = {
                'message': "Succesfully  opened Selenium.",
                # we don't know what kind of data this is, needs to be a dict/list though, so 
                # JsonResponse knows how to render it for the response
                'tags': tags 
            }

            if photos:
                data['photos'] = photos

            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response
```

That's the general idea, in my opinion: that content that you're currently trying to print needs to be shifted into the `data` dictionary that you're passing into the `JsonResponse`. That should result in a response along the lines of:

```
{
  "message": "Successfully opened Selenium.",
  "tags": [
    "no idea",
    "what kind",
    "of data",
    "this is"
  ],
  "photos": [
    "<div>Some sort of HTML content that Selenium scraped?</div>",
    "<div>Some sort of HTML content that Selenium scraped?</div>",
    "<div>Some sort of HTML content that Selenium scraped?</div>",
  ]
}
```

Again - not sure if this is *exactly* what you'll want to do, I'm just trying to illustrate a way to get that content out of your `print` statements, and into your `JsonResponse`. Glad to help further, just let me know if any other questions.